# How can I tell whether any crank is cold forged, hot forged or cast aluminium?

Tags: crankset, aluminum

I know that cold forging allows for sleeker designs because cold forged aluminium is stronger. Are there any other giveaways that indicate a certain manufacturing process?

Comment: Note that sleek doesn’t necessarily indicate a good manufacturing process or strong materials. Hollow crankarms look quite beefy but are actually lighter and stiffer than a solid counterpart. I’d look at the weight first and foremost, unless you are heavy or ride off-road.

Comment: I'm not aware that any cranks are cast. Even cheap Ashtabula cranks are forged.

Comment: The topic caught my interest after reading [this](https://bikeretrogrouch.blogspot.com/2016/01/old-is-good-specialized-triple-cranks.html) blog post stating the specialized ST crank being cold forged while the ST-4 is gravity cast.

Comment: Maybe even less widespread at the moment, but cranks may be also manufactured by CNC'ing and even 3D-printing.

Answer (score 2):

quoting Chris Bell:

Unfortunately all aluminium cranks look similar to the untrained eye so it is worth taking advice when buying a pair. Don't be fooled by the deliberate misuse of the term 'forged' as I've even seen that label written on the backs of poor-quality cast cranks. Fortunately, however, many cast cranks are perfectly strong enough for normal use.

From https://cornant.uk/info/cranks.html